# Is there any graphics library like this?

Tags: graphics, svg, png, gd, vector-graphics

IS there any graphic library meeting the following requirement.

1. can draw a point, a line, and a circle.
2. the size of canvas can be extended automatically.
3. support negative coordinates.
4. can output to png or any vectorgraph(like svg).
5. can draw characters (english only) (even characters rotated at a certain angle)

for e.g. 
I draw 2 point (-1,-1) (1,1). 
it will output a 2x2 sized picture. This left-top is the point(-1,-1). and the right-bottom is the point (1,1)

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course there are a couple of them. I would suggest you take a look and learn [OpenGL](http://www.opengl.org/). You can run it on Windows, Mac, Linux, iOS, Android, you name it.

It supports 2D and 3D rendering, and, even though is more complex than a regular 2D graphics library like CoreGraphics, it also more powerful.

Comment: OpenGL is raster-based, not vector-based, so it doesn't seem an intuitive fit for this problem (exporting a vectorgraph, particularly). In fact, it seems sort of like suggesting x86 assembly as a calculator. Yes, it would do the job perfectly - but it's not really suitable. Wouldn't something built atop OpenVG make more sense?

Comment: can you tell me some about imagemagick? can it meet the 5 requirements ?